# PHP for each not showing up in modal popup

Tags: php, html, sql

Using my SQL Select, I got each of my table rows to display correctly in my html table tag as you can see in the images. However when I click my modal tag in every row it only echos the first row in the whole table, in this case "cat1_tagname CHIROPRACTIC". Not sure why it does not echo based on the for each, looking for a solution.

I tried to add my foreach: `<?php foreach($lstTagMain as $rowTagOne) { ?>` inside the modal tag, but it displays every single one upon click.

```
<?php foreach($lstTagMain as $rowTagOne) { ?>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td class="col-md-1">
        <a href="category-coupon-list.php?c=1&c1=<?php echo($rowTagOne['product_cat1id']); ?>&c2=0&c3=0&t1=<?php echo($rowTagOne['cat1_tagname']); ?>&t2=0&t3=0"><img src="img/icon-add.png"></a>
      </td>

      <td class="col-md-1">
        <img src="img/icon-edit.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#category-edit-one">
        <div id="category-edit-one" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content address-modal">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title text-center"><?php echo($rowTagOne['cat1_tagname']); ?></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo($rowTagOne['cat1_tagname']); ?>" name="cat1_tagname" placeholder="Edit Category 1 Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12"><hr></div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <select class="form-control" name="producttagid" autocomplete="off" required>
                            <?php foreach ($lstTag as $rowTag) { ?>
                              <option class="strong" value="<?php echo $rowTag['producttagid']; ?>"><?php echo $rowTag['tagname']; ?></option>
                            <?php } ?>
                          </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12"><hr></div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <input type="submit" class="btn button-color-blue font-color-white full_width" name="add_category1" value="ADD">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

**SQL TABLE**
[image: 1]

**HTML TABLE**
[image: 2]

**MODAL**
[image: 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your markup add and unique in your for each like `<div class="modal-diaogue" I'd="<?php echo($rowTagOne['product_cat1id']); ?>">`
Then on your modal button add something like `<a href="#<?php echo($rowTagOne['product_cat1id']); ?>" open modal</a>` 
The idea is to make every modal unique so that you uniquely reference it when opening it

Comment: i see, i just needed to change the name on each instance of the modal, thanks